# How to keep application files in sails js

Tags: sails.js

I am developing sails js application.I stuck with small thing.I want to keep some application files with specific folder.

Thing is when we access that folder ,Some files inside that folder can be downloadable.How can i deploy it...?

Folder called **applicationData**

where should i keep that folder ..? how to access that folder..?

assets

```
 -applicationData
 -images
 -js
```

is that correct way ..? if it is correct then how can i access ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best way to access applicationData folder

**sails.config.appPath + '/api/applicationData/'**

when we create folder in assets it will go the .tmp/public

I suppose most suitable place in api folder